# tomcat and apache http together

Tags: 11.10, apache2, tomcat

can I install apache tomcat 6 and apache http web server on the same machine (Ubuntu 11.10) without problems ?

tomcat to serve GeoServer

apache web serve to serve static files

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. They are installed on a different places. But if you would like to run them together in the same time, you need to use different listening port of the webserver.

Apache HTTP Server is installed to listen on port 80, the default webserver port (use `localhost` in your browser). Tomcat6 comes configured to use 8080 (use `localhost:8080` in your browser)

So in default configurations the webservers do not clashes.